# Adding points without a question in the exam class

Tags: exam

In a test, I want to add some points for skills which are tested throughout the entire test. Therefore, they should not be appointed to a certain question.

I hence want to be able to write something like this:

- Correct usage of units: /1
- Correct usage of significant digits: /1

And then I want to add these points with the question points to obtain the total points.
Is this somehow possible?

Many thanks,
Sam